# Select Case vs Datatable.findrow performance in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have vb.net function which is referenced quite often that has a select case with 900 individual case values. It is a static list of names in alphabetical order. Has anyone had any experience with improving performance if I opted to create a table with a key column and looked up the value using data table find-row instead?

Creating the select case statement is easy and neat however is there a theoretical number of select case options where using such code becomes counter productive and better options should be employed?

EDIT FURTHER INFO

The select statement was created from a spreadsheet formula so no typing was involved. The problem is that the select statement opens up a number of variables so a case name "Michael" has surname = "blah", middle name = "blah", address = "blah" ......, DOB and a few others. Its all static and easily enough maintained AND it was what I could do at the time I wrote it. I know far more now so Im looking at improving the program. What Im trying to ascertain is if I could get better performance from changing the code and if it is worth it.

Comment: It almost causes physical pain to think about a Select Case statement with hundreds of cases. This is exactly what a Dictionary is for.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add some code to your question that shows us what a few of the case statements would look like.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it's meant specifically to store key/value pairs, with performance optimized for lookups. It only makes sense to create a data table, if you are already working with data tables in your application, to avoid maintenance overhead of keeping additional data structures. Otherwise bringing in a new concept will only complicate things, making it difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an actual benchmark, but consider this: If you have a table with an ordered list of values, a search for a random value will only have to search half the list on average. The code for this search is just a simple loop, and performance is very good for a modest list. The longer the list, the more benefit you will realize from a more sophisticated algorithm.

If you use a select-case, the compiler may generate efficient code or not. There isn't a good way to answer your question without testing (or intimate knowledge of the compiler), but testing this shouldn't be hard.

IMHO, for a list of 900 cases, I would use an alphabetical table and a binary search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Your code will look better, too.